# Is there a common way to check essential supremum?

Tags: measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Is there a common way to check essential supremum?

Particularly, my problem is in figuring out how to demonstrate that the measure is zero.

Comment: Please provide more context for your question. What is it that you are trying to demonstrate is measure zero? What are you taking the essential supremum of?

Comment: The essential supremum is used to define $\|f\|_{\infty}$ for $L^{\infty}$. Now if I need to evaluate $\|f\|_{\infty}$ for some $f$, then how do I do it?

Comment: This will be highly dependent on what $f$ you are considering.

Comment: @kccu Just something as an example. In order to illustrate the definition of $ess \space \sup$.

Comment: Do you have an example in mind that is relevant to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Show that the measure of $\{x:|f(x)|>M\}$ is zero. In this case $\|f\|_\infty\le M$. Find the smallest such $M$.

Comment: So to show that measure is zero one does what?

Comment: That will depend on the specific situation. One way, based on the decay of the measure of $\{x:|f(x)|>M\}$ (Call this quantity $F(M)$) is due to G. Stampacchia: If there are positive constants $a,b,C$ with $b<1$, and if $F(M)\le C(M-N)^{-a}[F(N)]^b$ for all $M>N\ge M_0$, then $F(M_0+K)=0$ for a $K$ that can be explicitly described in terms of $a,b,C$ and $F(M_0)$.